# Find the maximum value of $\frac{xyz}{(1+5x)(4x+3y)(5y+6z)(z+18)}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, multivariable-calculus, inequality, optimization, maxima-minima

Find the maximum value of $\frac{xyz}{(1+5x)(4x+3y)(5y+6z)(z+18)}$ as $x$, $y$, and $z$ range over all positive real numbers.

My first instinct was to apply AM-GM on each factor in the denominator since every variable is a positive real number. I also thought that it is just right to do so because minimizing the denominator would maximize the expression. The answer I got was $\frac{1}{2880}$, but the answer key states that it is $\frac{1}{5120}$. How come?

Answer (score 4):

It is equivalent to find the maximum for $w=\ln \frac{xyz}{(1+5x)(4x+3y)(5y+6z)(z+18)}$. Identify any critical point by setting $w_x'=w_y'=w_z'=0$, 
$$\frac1x=\frac5{1+5x}+\frac4{4x+3y}, \>\>\>\>\>
\frac1y=\frac5{5y+6z}+\frac3{4x+3y}, \>\>\>\>\>
\frac1z=\frac6{5y+6z}+\frac1{z+18}$$

Solve the equations for the point of positive solution at $(\frac35,\frac{12}5,6)$, which happens to admit the maximum value. Then, plug $(\frac35,\frac{12}5,6)$ into the expression to obtain

$$\frac{xyz}{(1+5x)(4x+3y)(5y+6z)(z+18)}=\frac1{5120}$$

Answer (score 4):

By AM-GM
$$\frac{xyz}{(1+5x)(4x+3y)(5y+6z)(z+18)}=$$
$$=\frac{xyz}{\left(1+3\cdot\frac{5x}{3}\right)(4x+3\cdot y)(5y+3\cdot2z)(z+3\cdot6)}\leq$$
$$\leq \frac{xyz}{4\sqrt[4]{1\cdot\left(\frac{5x}{3}\right)^3}\cdot4\sqrt[4]{4x\cdot y^3}\cdot4\sqrt[4]{5y\cdot(2z)^3}\cdot4\sqrt[4]{z\cdot6^3}}=\frac{1}{5120}.$$
The equality occurs for $$1=\frac{5x}{3},$$ $$4x=y,$$ $$5y=2z$$ and $$z=6$$ or $$(x,y,z)=\left(\frac{3}{5},\frac{12}{5},6\right),$$ which says that we got a maximal value.

Comment: How do you know dividing 5x, 3y, 6z and 18 into 3 parts give you values of x and z that give you the same value of y between 2nd and 3rd factors in the denominator, and would not contradict? Trial and error?

Comment: @Math Lover I don't remember now, how it was exactly. I think I saw that $\prod\limits_{cyc}\sqrt[4]{tx^3}=xyz,$ where $t=1$.

Answer (score 4):

Just another way, using an extended version of Holder’s inequality (or CS inequality repeatedly):
$$(1+5x)(4x+3y)(5y+6z)(z+18) \geqslant \left((1\cdot4x\cdot5y\cdot z)^{1/4}+(5x\cdot3y\cdot6z\cdot18)^{1/4} \right)^4 = 5120xyz$$
As equality is possible when $(x, y, z)=(\frac35, \frac{12}5, 6)$, this means the desired maximum is $\dfrac1{5120}$.

Comment: Wow, that's a very elegant solution!!!!!

Answer (score 3):

By AM-GM, we have
$$1+5x \ge 2\sqrt{5x}, ~\text{ Eq. when}~ x=1/5~~~~(1)$$
$$4x+3y \ge 2\sqrt{12xy}  ~\text{Eq. when}~y=4/15 ~~~~(2)$$
$$5x+6z \ge 2\sqrt{30xz} ~\text{Eq. when}~z=1/6 ~~~~~(3)$$
So
$$z+18 > 2\sqrt{18z}~~~~ ~\text{ as Eq. when}~z=18 (contradiction)~~~~ (4)$$
Multiplying them we get
$$(1+5x)(4x+3y)(5x+6z)(x+18) > 1440 xyz$$
$$\frac{xyz}{(1+5x)(4x+3y)(5x+6z)(x+18)} < \frac{1}{1440}.$$

Comment: There are a lot of typos, and it is not the maximum value

Comment: I have edited it, yes the LHS value is not attained.